# How do I track a parameter inside a method?

Tags: java

basically i need to track what the method does with the parameter, i can't modify the function to be tracked.

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is visually represent what the method does with the parameter.

I know java passes by value, so I'm having a hard time finding a workaround without modifying the method itself.

For example:

```
public void foo(int x){
   x+=10;
}
```

If I call it like this:

```
foo(2);
```

I need to be able to draw 2 rectangles, one with 2 width and one with 12.

I'd really appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Comment: So, from the sounds of things, you need some kind of stack or list to maintain a history of changes, unfortunately, there's no "magic" way you can do this without modifying either the method or those calling it

Comment: The method doesn't do anything. It only changes a local variable which is completely inaccessible from the outside. It wouldn't surprise me if the compiler removes it completely as an optimization.

Comment: Shoot. I've tried using a library with a name I can't remember. It let me create something called an Enhancer which let me intercept a method, and I tried adding a listener to the parameter before continuing with the method but unfortunately after the method is called the parameter switches back to its original value. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Ivar, yeah the method is just for a simple example. If it was a for loop, which prints some mathematical equations done to the parameter, would it make any difference?

Comment: @AhmedMaarek I'm not an expert in that field, so I can't give you a definite answer. It's not completely impossible. Debuggers are used to step through code, so you can use the same route that debuggers do, though it's probably not an easy exercise. (Although I have never tried it myself so who knows.)

Comment: @Ivar I'll give it a go and try and do that, but I really hope its not too complicated for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Java passes parameters by value, so the instruction inside the method

```
x += 10;
```

has no effect whatsoever on what was passed in, ie

```
int i = 2;
foo(i);
System.out.println(i); // 2
```

You would have to perform static code analysis to show what happens *inside* the method, noting that nothing actually happens to a variable passed in.

Comment: Got it, can you give me a tip on where to start reading about static code analysis?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis